# Explanation asked about the value of this -1

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
public myMethod(string s)
{
     string[] sa = s.Split(',');
     if (sa[1] != "" && sa[1] != "-1")
     {// do something}
}
```

what does the value of "-1" mean

Comment: it means string literal of value "-1", what else could it mean?

Comment: It means your second element of splited array is `"-1"` or not.

Comment: Is this a trick question? What do you expect it to be/do?

Comment: You need to see that "-1" as a string, not as a number.

Answer (score 2):

It means the string representation of -1 and not the integer before zero. In the same way it could mean "Hello", or "ten" or "apple"

It is also equal to

```
int myVar = -1; myVar.ToString();
```

in your case

```
 string[] sa = s.Split(',');
 if (sa[1] != "" && sa[1] != "-1")
 {// do something}
```

if **s** is "1,2,3,4" then your if statement will be executed, the code inside the if will run. BUT if your **s** is "1" OR "1," or "1,-1,1" it will not run.

Comment: thanx for the answer